# How do I resolve the same merge conflict in numerous files?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Assume I have this one conflict in 200 files:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/*  Version         1.0.0       */
/*  Date            2017-05-30  */
=======
/*  Version         1.0.1       */
/*  Date            2018-11-30  */
>>>>>>> release/1.0.1
```

I know for sure that I want the `1.0.1` version in all files. But simply using `--theirs` for all files is not feasible since I have other modifications too that shall be kept from `--ours`.

Is there a way to just resolve this one conflict with `--theirs` and then manually resolve other conflicts (in just a handfull of files) manually?

Comment: This seems like really bad design to me.  Why should the version number appear in _every_ source file?  If it were just a handful of files, you could use a regex to cleanup this particular conflict.

Comment: When we converted from CVS to Git a number of years ago, I tried to solve the same problem. It took me a while, but in the end I accepted that the version and date block do not actually belong in the source files. I have a RELEASES file where I document the version history, but for the source files I took it all out and rely on Git to track for me. Way fewer headaches!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've worked at more than a few corporations that enforce a byzantine "standard" header for every source file that shows a lack of understanding of the phrase "version control system"

Comment: @AndyBrown I believe it.  I have also worked in such environments and have seen similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think to make git do what you're asking during conflict resolution, would be to write a custom merge driver that detects and "fixes" the version info before invoking the normal `merge-file` process.  That's doable, but takes a bit of setup (see the `git attributes` docs under the `merge` attribute, where it talks about custom merge drivers).

If you can tolerate the extra step, it might be easier to just write a script (something like perl or even awk would be well-suited to the task) that finds and fixes that specific conflict block, and run that script over the conflicted merge output before going on to manually resolve the remaining changes.  The biggest down-side to this - and the reason I might consider the merge driver approach - is that if a file conflicts *only* due to the version block, you'll have no manual work but the file will still be in a conflicted state - so you'll have to check each file to see if there is remaining conflict resolution to be done.

It seems to me it might be wroth revisiting the aspect(s) of your workflow that lead you to expect these conflicts.

Comment: I have not tested this, but `git rerere` works based off individual diff hunks (with some edges shaved off, a la `git patch-id`) and therefore might also do the job.

Comment: @torek - I considered that, and I'm not sure.  (My `rerere` knowledge is so-so as I tend to just avoid its major use cases instead.)  I think my first question is whether the conflict is truly repeatable in a way that rerere would understand.  It sounds like similar (maybe even identical) conflict hunks occur across many files in one particular merge, but the next merge would have a slightly different conflict in all of those files - so not sure how that would be handled

Comment: I'm not sure either - I *think* the way this would work is that the merge would stop, you would hand-resolve one case, hand-invoke `git rerere` to record that resolution, and hand-invoke `git rerere` again to use the recording against the remaining unmerged files. But obviously I have not tried this—and I think it would be far better to stop doing silly things with the VCS...

Comment: Thanks. Went for the script fixing the conflict beforehand!